# Who are all these characters Squirrel Girl has beaten?

Tags: marvel, character-identification

[image: Adams Variant cover of The Squirrel Girl 1]

This image is taken from Adams Variant cover of *The Unbeatable Squirrel Girl* (2015) #1. Other than Squirrel Girl, I can identify Galactus, Thanos and Doctor Doom in it.

Who are the other characters?

Comment: Is it just me or should this have also asked when/whether she actually beat all of these characters? Or would that have been too broad?

Comment: @kaine I agree that would be interesting info but it's also stuff that you can just look up once you know who the characters are.

Comment: Any idea what that note is on Magneto's cloak? The image isn't quite high res enough to make out.

Comment: @DavidK ["Arthur Adams 9-29-2014"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRWEQ.png). You can find the whole cover in high res [here](https://www.previewsworld.com/Catalog/NOV140897).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[image: Image marked up with alphabetic labels for each character]

Numbered Image Courtesy of b_jonas

[A] Big Purple head = Galactus

[B] Squirrel Girl

[C] Giant Dragon = Fin Fan Foom

[D] Red face, Saber = Red Skull

[E] Tiger Shark(Courtesy of Vanja)

[F] Fur coat Hairy chest = Kraven the Hunter

[G] purple face, blue yellow outfit = Thanos

[H] Tippy-Toe, Squirrel side-kick

[I] Robot face Green cloak = Doctor Doom

[J] Glowface robot = Ultron

[K] Green face purple outfit = The Green Goblin

[L] Flaming Skull = Dormammu

[M] Girl with green green crown? = Enchantress

[N] Wendigo (Courtesy of Irishpanda)

[O] Redhead, blue body = Mystique

[P] Red outfit next to Mystique = Magneto

[R] Guy in Rhino suit = Rhino

[S] lizard head = The Lizard

[T] Blastaar (courtesy of Vanja)

[U] Green Guy on Galactus's shoulder = Abomination(Courtesy of Irishpanda) or Ch'od (wearing purple pants, Courtesy of Vanja)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69386/discussion-on-answer-by-joeryjv-who-are-all-these-characters-squirrel-girl-has-b).

Comment: Wrong answer. Question is about who are the character Squirrel Girls has beaten but Galactus, Kraven, Red Skull and Tiger Shark looks quite standing and in good shape.

Comment: I think the question presumes that Squirrel Girl has defeated all of them, even if they are not literally unconscious.

Comment: you [can add](https://i.imgur.com/Z6NP8zV.png) a black [outline](https://i.imgur.com/JHvDb.png) around [the bright](https://i.imgur.com/QB6FExj.png) text [for clarity](https://i.imgur.com/kFyM7xo.jpg)

Comment: Is U not more likely to be the hulk ?

Comment: The Hulk isn't a villian

Comment: I thought "T" looked like Ulik.. Thor's villain.

Comment: Isn't C Fin Fang Foom, not Foon (https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Fin_Fang_Foom_(Earth-616))?

Comment: @JoeryJV Nobody said they had to be villains. Even if they did [Hulk isn't always a good guy](https://www.cbr.com/hulk-greatest-villain-and-hero/)

Comment: @OrangeDog - It's Dormammu. Squirrel girl faced him in Vol 6.; https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/S/cmx-images-prod/Item/598235/Previews/bcc4812c4118f3b3fb3b33ac44846362._SX1280_QL80_TTD_.jpg

Comment: @JamesD - U is Abomination. She and Hulk faced him together in a redux of her origin story.

Comment: @Valorum ah yes, on the high-res version I realised where his head/body was.

Comment: @Shreedhar "I thought "T" looked like Ulik.. Thor's villain." - Agreed, the costume and hair colour match Ulik, not Blastaar.

Answer (score 11):

(Using the labels on the image in the other answer)

[C] Fin Fang Foom is green dragon

[D] Red Skull if in front of him with sword

[G] Thanos - she has her foot on him

[R] Rhino (Aleksei Sytsevich) - is under him

[L] Dormammu  is right of him (guy with fire head)

[J] Ultron is left of Rhino

[K] Green Goblin under Rhino's leg

[I] Doctor Doom next to ultron

[S] Lizard (Curtis Connors) - is in bottom right corner

[A] Galactus  top left corner

[E] Tiger Shark is below him

[F] Kraven the Hunter left of him

[P] Magneto is bottom left corner

[O] Mystique next to Mgneto

[T] Blastaar