# Does Squirrel Girl have maxed power stats on the Marvel Wiki?

Tags: marvel, squirrel-girl

According to [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/8464/68872) on the question:  "[How did Squirrel Girl defeat Dr Doom?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8454/how-did-squirrel-girl-defeat-dr-doom)", all of Squirrel Girls power stats are "maxed" out.

According to the answer, I am supposed to be able to check [Squirrel Girl's entry](http://marvel.com/universe/Squirrel_Girl#axzz5EPfkx42T) on the official Marvel wiki and be able to see her power stats there.

However I'm unable to see any maxed stats in her entry on the page.

Comment: The widget that shows the stats requires Adobe Flash for some reason.

Comment: Do you actually want to know what her stats are (as the title suggests) or just be told where on the page the layout that shows the stats is (as the body of your question seems to imply). The better question to me is the former and if so the answers probably need to focus more on whether the numbers actually reflect her power levels as shown in the comics or if this is just a marvel joke showing her to be the most powerful thing ever...

Comment: @Chris it seems from the body of the question that op is wanting to know what her stats are on the website

Comment: @Valorum: indeed. This doesn't seem to be a very good question to me though which is why I made the comment. "Can you tell me what this web page says" doesn't feel very on topic since it doesn't require any knowledge of sci-fi or fantasy - just an ability to click on a link and read a chart. I'm very confused as to whether I am missing something or whether this question could be improved since the fact its had at least 16 upvotes means that some people see more merit in it than I do...

Comment: @Chris - The problem is that there are potentially two questions; What does it say on the site? / does this accurately reflect her observed powers? For me the latter question is the more interesting. I might ask it later.

Comment: @Valorum: I completely agree and have commented such further down. I just wasn't sure if the +15 score meant I was missing something. I'm not going to worry about it any more than I have though. I've made comments saying my thoughts, I've placed my vote. Not much more to do now. :)

Comment: This isn't a very good questions becuase it's asking specifically about the contents of the wiki and not about the character's actual capabilities.

Comment: This is a very good question because it has many votes.

Comment: @OrangeDog: it's a missed opportunity that the stats widget doesn't require Adobe Quicksilver instead.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

## Yes<sup>1</sup>

At the bottom of her page named "in comics full report" you can see her power stats showing a full set of stats.

[image: Squirrel Girl power stats showing all 7s]

Comparing this with Thanos' stats shows that she's even got higher average stats than he does!

[image: Thanos' power stats showing lower stats. Durability - 6, Energy - 6, Fighting Skills - 4, Intelligence - 6, Speed - 7, Strength - 7]

Another example of someone with full stats is [Eternity](https://www.marvel.com/characters/eternity):

[image: Eternity's power stats showing full stats]

---

### <sup>1</sup>

As mentioned by Valorum in the comments, it is possible this is a joke in part from marvel about a superhero with Squirrel powers being one of the most powerful beings in the galaxy. While this isn't necessarily clear from the entry, it is a possibility given the *Official Handbook on the Marvel Universe* has differing power levels for the character.

Comment: Ah, the perils of quoting a wiki. I think the author is having a bit of fun with you.

Comment: @Valorum this isn't _a_ wiki. This is the officially maintained marvel wiki, effectively WoG if you want to so believe it. You're welcome to think your book is "more canonical" it would however seem to be out-of-date, if that was the fact.

Comment: I challenge you to show me an occasion when she's used any of these maxed stats. You're telling me she's omniscient, has incalculable strength, can outrun any character, is indestructible, can command all forms of energy and is a master of all forms of combat? Really really? http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Power_Grid

Comment: @Valorum I'm not saying anything. All I'm showing is that the source from the answer in the other question is correct in stating that on the official marvel.com wiki, her power grid is maxed out. That is what the question asked, and that is the answer I have provided.

Comment: @Edlothiad: The problem is the title of the question asks if Squirrel girl has maxed stats whereas the body of the question seems more focussed about where the maxed stats are on the page.

Comment: @Chris sure one could see it as a slight oversight, but one shouldn't base a good answer simply on a title. The body is where the context of the question is set and the question well and truly fleshed out.

Comment: @Edlothiad: I'm not trying to criticize the answer, just countering your "I'm not saying anything" by pointing out why people *might* think you are saying that. I'd edit the question to make the title and body match but I don't think "Where is this information on this web page" is actually a good question so I don't want the title changed to that and changing the body to be more about "What are squirrel girls stats" is too substantial a change to make, especially given answers such as this which as you say focus on the body rather than the title.

Comment: She's the *Unbeatable* Squirrel Girl for a reason ;)

Comment: It would make more sense if her ability to defeat anyone was listed as a separate power a la reality warping, but that would ruin the joke a bit. Still, that's effectively what the max stats translate to. Arguing that she's a plain old supreme being (possibly only off page and when convenient) becomes hard to maintain in light of the fact that she doesn't seem to be aware of that herself.

Comment: I think it's a joke because Squirrel Girl is a CS student in her "normal" life. She hacked the page for fun.

Comment: Flatman has similar stats

Comment: While this may be literally correct in that OP is asking about the Marvel Wiki in particular, there's no way this is correct. I doubt she can move at speeds that would make the USS Starship Enterprise feel ashamed, or withstand being in the center of a hypernova.

Comment: @forest Marvel lie on their official wiki. Would they ever?!

Comment: Never underestimate the power of being liked by the writers.

Comment: @forest You say that, but she once beat Thanos single-handedly.

Answer (score 15):

Per the [Official Marvel Handbook (2005 - Avengers edition)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Official_Handbook_of_the_Marvel_Universe), her real [stats](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Power_Grid) are as follows. All are well within the "normal" range for an enhanced human, (which incidentally fits in with what we see her doing in her comics).

> [image]
>
> Intelligence - Human normal
> Strength - Superhuman (lift 800 lbs-25 ton range)
> Speed - Superhuman (peak range: 700 MPH)
> Durability: Enhanced
> Energy Projection: None
> Fighting Skills: Experienced fighter

Her stats in the more recent [Official Marvel Handbook A-Z (2008)](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Official_Handbook_of_the_Marvel_Universe_A-Z_Vol_1) have identical stats for her as well as a blurb that describes her as a '*surprisingly fierce and formidable unarmed opponent*' but by no means possessed of god-like abilities.

> [image]

---

As an example, if her stats were actually "maxed out" [this fight](https://hqbr.com.br/hqs/uploads/picture/image/324745/Novos_Vingadores_015__2011___MK-SQ_-008.jpg) would have ended within nanoseconds, assuming he could even perceive her within his limited plane of existence.

Comment: Given the question is looking for the stats stated on the wiki at Marvel.com, I fail to see how this truly answers the question?

Comment: @Edlothiad - Because the stats at the marvel wiki are incorrect and are (I assume) intended humourously.

Comment: Well you're going to need a citation that the stats haven't simply been revised in the past 13 years.

Comment: @Edlothiad - I picked up the most recent edition of SG. She's a college counsellor. She often relies on her squirrels to help her win battles. I see her fighting goons on Earth, not challenging Galactus for control of the universe.

Comment: And yet she has defeated (other than Dr Doom), at various points, greater enemies that are arguably incredibly powerful such as Thanos and Ego.  If cover art is an indicator, one could argue that she *has* actually defeated Galactus.  [See here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/175149/who-are-all-these-characters-squirrel-girl-has-beaten) for a longer list.

Comment: @Doc - That's quite literally the joke. She defeats people who should (theoretically) be able to outmatch her easily.

Answer (score 13):

Look at the Power Grid at the top right of [the page](http://marvel.com/universe/Squirrel_Girl#axzz5EPfkx42T). All stats are at 7 out of 7.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The layout has changed so I thought I would reply with a modern answer.

You just have to go to her ["in comics full report"](https://www.marvel.com/characters/squirrel-girl-doreen-green/in-comics) and scroll all the way to the very bottom. She scores a near-unbelievable all 7's!

[image: Squirrel Girl's in-comics stats (All 7's)]

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  This does answer the question, but it's not really different from the existing answers.  You should check out the pointers for [writing good answers](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).